# The names of treble and bass notes

Tags: theory, terminology, octave

A video I saw said the C note and octave above middle C is called Treble C, and the C below middle C is called Bass C.  He didn't mention other notes.  Would the same be true referring to the D note on the treble staff as treble D?

I assume ALL the notes in the treble staff (E through F) are called treble notes and same for bass notes.   And any notes above the treble staff are called high C, high D and below the bass staff is low C, low D, etc.? Is that the correct music terminology?

Something isn't right because there are two D notes above middle C. They wouldn't both be treble D.

Comment: Care to share the video? The concept is flawed - there are two E notes on the treble clef- I assume that's where the naming comes from, and two A notes on the bass clef. So the idea isn't too safe, and probably erroneous. Other notes are doubled too, and would the D above middle c be called middle D - in fact, on piano, there's a lot of logic to that being the case!

Comment: Whoever made that video I think made things confusing for you. I’ve never hear the terms “treble C” or “treble D” or “bass F” or anything like that. I think the video maker just invented that and it’s not a very good naming system. I suggest a solid textbook on music theory instead of questionable YouTube videos.

Comment: FWIW, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(musical_note) mentions "Treble C", and https://music.stackexchange.com/a/69568/18896 mentions "Bass C" - whatever this video is, it doesn't seem to be the only place to use these terms...

Comment: I always thought the C above Middle C was "High C" and the C below Middle C was "Low C".

Comment: Faber piano books use treble C and bass C as well. I find it useful because C's then function as landmark notes to make finding other notes easier.

Comment: I would recommend avoiding this terminology, especially if you are playing an instrument from the saxophone family (for which all notes are in the treble clef, even for the contrabass saxophone). It's much better to refer to those notes as Middle C, Low C and High C, like @Dekkadeci suggested.

Comment: @Dekkadeci the identity of "high C" depends on context.  It is the C above middle C for tenors; it is an octave higher for sopranos.  (I suppose there are other contexts in which the phrase is used, but I can't say with certainty how it is defined in those contexts.)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to really be clear about what pitch is intended is to use a system that indicates the octave like Helmholtz or Scientific Pitch Notation.

'Names' can be unclear. 'Middle C' has a clear meaning, it's `C4`. But names like 'high C' aren't clear. For a soprano a high C is `C6`, but for a tenor it is `C5`.

This [wiki chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(musical_note)#Designation_by_octave) shows a combination of octave naming.

Comment: I've read on this website that some keyboard systems use C3 for Middle C instead of C4.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, is that an electronic versus acoustic thing? (Either way it reinforces the main point.)

Comment: The note name + octave number system isn't perfect either. Some systems start at -1, some - at 0, and some start at 1... That's particularly noticeable with certain DAW's (like Renoise) and VST's. For the saxophone "Middle C" is a term used to refer to what is in effect a "median" C. 3 different C's can be played within the instrument's formal range, the 1st one is called "Low C", the 2nd one is called "Middle C" and the 3rd one - "High C". This is probably similar to what you tried to explain referring to human vocal ranges.

Answer (score 1):

There is an established naming convention which uses the words - Bass, Treble, High and Low to identify specific notes:

[image]

I am trying to figure this out myself, but it looks like the names originate with this Landmark System for learning the musical staff -
https://standrewspianotuition.co.uk/natural-piano/the-landmark-system

It looks like it only refers to the particular landmark notes used.

https://app.hoffmanacademy.com/lessons/piano/guide-notes-low-c-high-c/video/

https://www.pianowithsarah.ca/blog/landmark-notes-high-and-low-c

https://www.reddit.com/r/piano/comments/18x0q77/2_landmark_systems_pros_and_cons_of_each/

Comment: I dismissed the 1st video as his own ideas, not a well accepted concept. And not particularly helpful anyway. Never come across those ideas in decades of playing. And don't even work convincingly on piano, let alone any other instrument. Not good.

Comment: The *Piano with Sarah* video unfortunately calls the “bass C” and “treble C” in your image “low C” and “high C” respectively.  The [Dolmetsch dictionary](https://www.dolmetsch.com/musictheory1.htm#octaves) (perhaps a more authoritative source) uses the terms “pedal”, “bass”, “middle”, “treble”, and “top”.  But it also gives each of these an entire octave of notes, so that that “treble G” in your image is called “middle G” — it’s all very confusing.