# What does a "2" on top of a figured bass exercise mean?

Tags: notation, figured-bass

Here is a pic from my textbook, Adwell/Schachter's *Tonal Harmony*. It tells me what the soprano should be in the figured bass but there is a 2 next to both notes. What does that mean?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance those are footnotes explained at the bottom of the page? Looks strange to me. Let's see if anyone's got an answer for it.

Comment: whole page added, although I cant see anything that relates to that.... hmmm does it maybe apply to how many octaves above the bass the soprano should be written?

Answer (score 6):

These numbers indicate what we call *octave designation*, which these authors discuss in their chapter on key/scale/modes (depending on what edition of the book you have, these chapters may be separated).

With that said, the system they're using treats Middle C as C<sup>1</sup>. This means that Middle C is C<sup>1</sup>, the C an octave above that (the third space in treble clef) is C<sup>2</sup>, etc. Everything between C<sup>1</sup> and C<sup>2</sup> is labelled as a 1, everything between C<sup>2</sup> and C<sup>3</sup> (the C above the treble clef) is labelled as a 2, etc.

Thus the annotation here is telling you that your soprano pitch, D♭<sup>2</sup>, will be the fourth line of the treble clef, because it's the one within the C<sup>2</sup> octave. In the next chord, that soprano will move up a major third to the nearby F<sup>2</sup>.

I've discussed octave designation in my answer to [How do you refer to a note that is more than one octave above or below middle C?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/69373/21766), but you'll notice that this specific system isn't in my answer. That's because this system is a variant of the Helmholtz system at the bottom of my answer, but one that uses Arabic numerals instead of hash marks.

Comment: In German music notation, a combination of upper and lower case letters and numbers is used, and the middle C is "c1", but I'm not sure where else in the world [this system](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_(Musik)#/media/Datei:Klaviernotation.png) is used.

Comment: PS: I didn't know it has a name, but indeed, afaik, Helmholtz-notation is the standard in Germany