# Schoenberg notation

Tags: notation, overtones

In [Theory of Harmony](https://archive.org/details/theoryofharmonyschoenberg/page/n33/mode/2up) section 4 on the major mode and diatonic chords by Schoenberg, he writes,

> A musical sound is a composite, made up of a series of tones sounding together, the overtones; hence, it forms a chord. From a fundamental, C, these overtones are:
>
> c, g, c<sup>1</sup>, e<sup>1</sup>, g<sup>1</sup>, (b-flat)<sup>1</sup>, c<sup>2</sup>, d<sup>2</sup>, e<sup>2</sup>, f<sup>2</sup>, g<sup>2</sup>, etc.

What do the superscripts mean in this context? An octave above the fundamental?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtone in particular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtone#Overtones_in_music_composition

Comment: Wikipedia's [Harmonic series (music)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(music)) is good, too.

Comment: Schoenberg is using Helmholtz notation with integers instead of slashes; see [this answer here](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/69373/21766).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the superscripts indicate (one less than) the number of octaves above the fundamental. It's a variation on Helmholz notation, which uses prime symbols (c' c'' c''') rather than superscript numerals.

In standard notation:

```
X: 1
T: Harmonic Series (from C1)
M: none
L: 1/1
K: none
[V:V1] "_C"x "_c"x "_g"x "_c1"x "_e1"x "_g1"x "_b♭1"x "_c2"C "_d2"D "_e2"E "_f2"F "_g2"G
[V:V2 clef=bass] C,,, C,, G,, C, E, G, _B,
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "zero-based," but isn't the number actually one less than the number of octaves above the fundamental?

Comment: @Richard Yes, I was looking for a way to express that. The superscripts indicate octaves above the octave above the fundamental. Do you think my edit clarifies things? My concern is it creates more questions.

Comment: @Richard Do you think it would make more sense for me to just say it's a variation on Helmholz notation using superscripts rather than prime symbols?

Comment: I think your edit is clear, but your latter solution is how I've always addressed it. Hence why I've always preferred the C4-as-Middle-C system!